# vuejs Pagination GET Url Params

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I am using https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination pagination it works fine.I have included pagination in the page as below

```
<pagination :data="posts" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
```

and the method

```
        getResults(page = 1) {
                    axios.get('api/post?page=' + page)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.posts = response.data;
                        });
            },
```

Now when i searchBy Category the pagination links shows api/findByCategoy?category=5&page=1

```
        selectCatgory(e) {
                   axios.get('api/findByCategoy?category=' + e.target.value)
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.posts = data.data
                    })
                    .catch(() => {

                    })
        },
```

I have inclded the GET params in the url . How to change the path in  the getResults

```
public function searchByCategory(){

    if ($search = \Request::get('category')) {
        $posts = Post::where('category_id',$search)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(20);
        $querystringArray = Input::only(['category']);
        $posts->appends($querystringArray);
    }else{
        $posts = Post::latest()->paginate(10);
    }

    return $posts;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.get('api/findByCategoy?category=' + e.target.value + '&page=1')
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: May want to encodeURIComponent `e.target.value`; alternatively, `axios.get('api/findByCategoy', {params: { page: page, category: e.target.value }})`